# Integrate two buttons dropdown toggle open

Tags: html, css

I am trying to integrate two buttons into one. So when you click the little V icon button the dropdown menu opens. But I would like that to happen also when you click the button with the title. Basically the two buttons (V-icon and title) should be one. Is that possible?

```css
.btn_clear {
    float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 29px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:blue;
 color:#FFF;
}
  
.btn_apply {
    float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 17px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:red;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Car brand</button> <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class=
            "caret"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu car-brand">
                <div class="typeahead-box">
                    <input class="car brand" placeholder=
                    "Car brand" type="text">
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class=" scrollable-menu" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
                        <ul>
                          <li>mercedes</li>
                          <li>audi</li>
                          <li>volvo</li>
                          <li>renault</li>
                          </ul>
                      
                        <div class="div_form">
                            <span class="btn_apply">Apply</span> <span class=
                            "btn_clear">Clear</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Car brand</button>
```

Instead of

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Car brand</button>
```

```css
.btn_clear {
    float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 29px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:blue;
 color:#FFF;
}
  
.btn_apply {
    float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 17px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:red;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Car brand</button> <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class=
            "caret"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu car-brand">
                <div class="typeahead-box">
                    <input class="car brand" placeholder=
                    "Car brand" type="text">
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class=" scrollable-menu" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
                        <ul>
                          <li>mercedes</li>
                          <li>audi</li>
                          <li>volvo</li>
                          <li>renault</li>
                          </ul>
                      
                        <div class="div_form">
                            <span class="btn_apply">Apply</span> <span class=
                            "btn_clear">Clear</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: sorry, ofcourse it works! I got it mixed up... long day... :) Thank you!

Comment: It's okay. Please choose my answer as correct as it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the "Car Brands" the same way you have it in the carat element.

Like so:

```css
.btn_clear {
    float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 29px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:blue;
 color:#FFF;
}
  
.btn_apply {
    float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 17px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 background-color:red;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Car brand</button> <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class=
            "caret"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu car-brand">
                <div class="typeahead-box">
                    <input class="car brand" placeholder=
                    "Car brand" type="text">
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class=" scrollable-menu" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
                        <ul>
                          <li>mercedes</li>
                          <li>audi</li>
                          <li>volvo</li>
                          <li>renault</li>
                          </ul>
                      
                        <div class="div_form">
                            <span class="btn_apply">Apply</span> <span class=
                            "btn_clear">Clear</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```